# RSelenium Drop-Down Menu Selection

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm trying to use `RSelenium` to select an option from a drop-down menu, and am using XPath to locate the element I'm interested in.

The website is: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=%282019-03-01%5BDate+-+Publication%5D+%3A+2019-03-31%5BDate+-+Publication%5D%29+AND+%28Hearing+Loss%5BMeSH+Terms%5D%29&size=200 and I'm trying to save the results in `PMID` format. My code selects the Format box, but when I want it to click the `PMID` option, it doesn't do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my code:

```r
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", "#save-results-panel-trigger")

webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "enter"))

webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//*[(@id = 'save-action-format')]")

webElem$clickElement()

remDr$findElement(using = "xpath","//*[(@value='pmid')]")$clickElement()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `PMID` of all articles of the current page through,

1. Using `rvest`

```
'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=%282019-03-01%5BDate+-+Publication%5D+%3A+2019-03-31%5BDate+-+Publication%5D%29+AND+%28Hearing+Loss%5BMeSH+Terms%5D%29&size=200' %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_nodes('.docsum-pmid') %>% html_text()

[1] "30842313" "30916228" "30920067" "30782832" "30471777" "30905565" "30892661" "30847886" "30954364" "30639959" "29555078" "31184964" "30634102" "30632288"
```

Similarly from second page,

```
    'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=%282019-03-01%5BDate+-+Publication%5D+%3A+2019-03-31%5BDate+-+Publication%5D%29+AND+%28Hearing+Loss%5BMeSH+Terms%5D%29&size=200&page=2' %>% 
      read_html() %>% html_nodes('.docsum-pmid') %>% html_text()
     [1] "30338413" "30833669" "30909120" "30623325" "30894283" "30324407" "30740830" "30682699" "30287322" "30929520" "30850599" "30907643" "30887954" "29927780"
```

2. Using `RSelenium`

```
    library(RSelenium)
    #open browser 
    driver = rsDriver(
         port = 4847L,
           browser = c("firefox"))
    
    remDr <- driver[["client"]]
    
    url = 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=%282019-03-01%5BDate+-+Publication%5D+%3A+2019-03-31%5BDate+-+Publication%5D%29+AND+%28Hearing+Loss%5BMeSH+Terms%5D%29&size=200'
    remDr$navigate(url)

    #click on SAVE 
    remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'//*[@id="save-results-panel-trigger"]')$clickElement()
    
    #click of selection
    address_element <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '//*[@id="save-action-selection"]')
    address_element$sendKeysToElement(list("all-results"))
    
    #click of format 
    address_element <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '//*[@id="save-action-format"]')
    address_element$sendKeysToElement(list("pmid"))
    
    #finally click on Create file
    remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'//*[@id="save-action-panel-form"]/div[3]/button[1]')$clickElement()
    
    #close browser
    remDr$close()
```